# How to update the Bridge table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, sql-update

I have three tables `tblSubject`, `tblSubjectGroup` and `tblSubjectGroupDetails`.

`tblSubject` table has the following columns:

```
subId (PK, char(36), not null)
subName (varchar(50), not null)
```

`tblSubjectGroup` table has these columns:

```
subGroupId (PK, char(36), not null)
subGroupName (varchar(50), not null)
```

`tblSubjectGroupDetails` is the bridge table between the above tables which have a many-to-many relationship:

```
subGroupId (FK, char(36), not null)
subId (FK, char(36), not null)
```

I put the following dummy data in these tables:

**tblSubject**:

English, Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry, Science, Biology, Economics, Geography, History

**tblSubjectGroup**:

Group1, Group2,Group3

- `Group1` is linked to `English, Mathematics and Biology`
- `Group2` is linked to `Geography, History and Economics`
- `Group3` is linked to `Physics, Chemistry and Science`

Here, I want to update the `Group2` with these subjects: `Geography, History, Science.`

(Inserting and deleting is fine for me, but I can't figure out how to update the bridge table)

```
UPDATE tblSubjectGroupDetails 
SET subId = '......' 
WHERE subGroupId = '......'
```

The above statement will change all the subjects of a particular subjectGroup. I want to change only Economics to Science for Group2.

By the way, I forgot to mention that `tblSubjectGroupDetails` has a composite primary key.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: what codes have you tried so far? is there an update statement that is not working? maybe you can include it in your post so that we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: Why would you update the bridging table? Its far easier to delete the unwanted entries and add the desired entries. Updating just adds complexity.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Oh I see! This is one way of solution.

Comment: Its either that, or do two steps 1) Delete any in the bridge table that are not in your new list, and 2) add any in the new list that are not in the bridge table; or alternatively use a merge statement, that can merge between your new list and the existing list.

Comment: Merge Statement? That's new to me. I will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change only Economics to Science for Group2.

You need another condition in your where clause, like so:

```
UPDATE tblSubjectGroupDetails SET subId = science_id
WHERE subGroupId = group_2_id
  and subId = economics_id;
```

Just replace the IDs with the correct values.

Of course, this will not work (will generate a primary key constraint violation) if your Group2 has already a Science subject record in that table.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider to check the condition.